# Pasting a row multiple times based on the range in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not able to get my head around this problem. I am copying the cells in a `row` `A2:C2` from one sheet to another sheet but I want to paste them in multiple `rows` based on the cells filled on the adjacent `column` `D`. I am able to populate the `column` `D` with the appropriate range.
My problem is how to determine the range length and paste the cells `A2:C2` that many times. Here is the code which i tried to write. I `declared` all the `variables` before. This is the part of code where i'm having issues. Thank you all!
[Excel Sheet Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxNW23K23hUGUTc1VjJKbUFTZGs)

```
lastrow1 = Sheets("ResourcesLib").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To lastrow1
    resources = Sheets("ResourcesLib").Cells(i, "A").Value
    Sheets("sheet3").Activate
    lastrow2 = Sheets("sheet3").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For j = 2 To lastrow2
    If Sheets("sheet3").Cells(j, "B").Value = resources Then
        Sheets("ResourcesLib").Activate
        NoCell = rsrcl.Cells(i, rsrcl.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        rsrcl.Range(rsrcl.Cells(i, 2), rsrcl.Cells(i,rsrcl.Cells(i,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy
        rsrca.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        Sheets("sheet3").Activate
        Sheets("sheet3").Cells(j, "A").Copy
        rsrca.Range(Cells(k, 1), Cells(m + (NoCell - 1), 1)).PasteSpecial
        Sheets("sheet3").Cells(j, "B").Copy
        rsrca.Range(Cells(k, 2), Cells(m + (NoCell - 1), 2)).PasteSpecial
        Sheets("sheet3").Cells(j, "C").Copy
        rsrca.Range(Cells(k, 3), Cells(m + (NoCell - 1), 3)).PasteSpecial
    End If

Next j
k = (NoCell - 2) + k
m = k
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a real problem here, could you expand on what is happening in the code, I follow it up to `NoCell` and `rsrcl`.

Comment: @GaryEvans so after rsrcl, the cells are copied from that sheet and pasted in rsrca column D (transposed). After this line is the problem. I need to copy cells A3:C3 cells if (j=3) from "Sheet3" and paste in rsrca A to C columns but paste it multiple times until the end of the pasted column "D" (transposed) in the previous step. I hope you got an idea. 
So what i did is I'am copying the cells specifying a range with NoCell as the upperlimit for for loop but seems not to work. 
I can send you the ecel file for better understanding. Thanks!

Comment: very sorry, there is not enough here for me to understand what you are trying to, hopefully someone else can follow it better than me.

Comment: @GaryEvans   I added the excel sheet. Please have a look at it. I hope it gives an idea.

Comment: What did you set rsrcl and rsrca equal to?

Comment: @Rodger rsrcl = sheets("resourcelib")
                rsrca = sheets("resources")
The excel file attached would give a better idea of what i'm trying to achieve.you can see the code as well. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, been looking at that already. Just needed to know what those were in terms of ranges/sheets/etc so that I can use them correctly in the answer

Comment: when you say "range length" range length of what part? this line or a different line/different range? rsrcl.Range(rsrcl.Cells(i, 2), rsrcl.Cells(i, rsrcl.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy

Comment: Yes that is the line for the range length, but when we paste it in the rsca sheet the cells in that range are transposed and pasted in Column "D".

Comment: Clear resources sheet before you run that and you should have a line for line match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
Sub Transfer()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, Lastcolumn As Long, k As Long, m As Long
Dim Firstrow As Long, Lastrow As Long, NoCell As Long
Dim activity As String, resources As String
Dim rsrcl As Worksheet, rsrca As Worksheet
Dim aRsrclRange
Dim iRangeLength
Dim lastrowtemp As Long

Set rsrcl = Sheets("ResourcesLib")
Set rsrca = Sheets("Resources")
k = 2
m = 1
NoCell = 2
iRangeLength = 1 ' default to 1 for the lines that only have a single value ... they won't be arrays

'Adding Resources to activities
lastrow1 = Sheets("ResourcesLib").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To lastrow1
    resources = Sheets("ResourcesLib").Cells(i, "A").Value
    Sheets("sheet3").Activate
    lastrow2 = Sheets("sheet3").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For j = 2 To lastrow2
        If Sheets("sheet3").Cells(j, "B").Value = resources Then
            Sheets("ResourcesLib").Activate
            NoCell = rsrcl.Cells(i, rsrcl.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            rsrcl.Range(rsrcl.Cells(i, 2), rsrcl.Cells(i, rsrcl.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy 'put range into clipboard for paste transpose
            aRsrclRange = rsrcl.Range(rsrcl.Cells(i, 2), rsrcl.Cells(i, rsrcl.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)) 'put range into array for ubound calculation
            If IsArray(aRsrclRange) Then iRangeLength = UBound(aRsrclRange, 2) 'get the length of the range that was copied
            rsrca.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
            Sheets("sheet3").Activate
            Sheets("sheet3").Range(Cells(j, "A"), Cells(j, "C")).Copy 'Copy a through c at the same time since you are pasting them in a row
            lastrowtemp = Sheets("Resources").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'get current last row on resources
            While iRangeLength > 0 'paste on last line number of times equal to array length
                lastrowtemp = lastrowtemp + 1
                rsrca.Activate
                If IsArray(aRsrclRange) Then
                    rsrca.Range(Cells(lastrowtemp, 1), Cells(lastrowtemp, UBound(aRsrclRange, 2))).PasteSpecial
                Else
                    rsrca.Range(Cells(lastrowtemp, 1), Cells(lastrowtemp, 1)).PasteSpecial
                End If
                iRangeLength = iRangeLength - 1
            Wend
            iRangeLength = 1 'back to 1 for the lines with only 1 value
        End If
    Next j
    k = (NoCell - 2) + k
    m = k
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: you are a genius!!

Comment: Happy to help! :-) Hopefully the comments will show you how it was done so next time you got it on your own. :-)